# Should these interfaces be inherited at interface level or implemented at class level?

Tags: c#, interface

I am creating a console application for the purpose of learning the state and observer patterns. The program is based on a basic order system whereby each order can have a state (pending, ready, submitted i.e state pattern) and subscribers that are interested in receiving notifications from the order when it gets updated are notified (observer pattern).

The Order class is implementing three interfaces; `IOrder`, `IOrderState` and `IObservable` but I realised that instead I could have the interfaces inheriting from each other. Which approach would be better? When would you make the class implement from each of the interfaces separately instead of having say, `IOrder` inherit from the other two?

For example:

```
public class Order : IOrder, IOrderState, IObservable
```

or

```
public interface IOrder : IOrderState, IObservable
```

**edit**
I may have just answered my question - am I right in thinking you would make the IOrder interface inherit from the other two interfaces if you are sure the object that will implement it (the Order class) will always need to use those methods? And if you're not sure if an interfaces methods are needed, or if other classes i.e perhaps an order that does not need to be observed by subscribers, then you would include the interfaces separately at class level?

Comment: Has your IOrder any meaning without those other two interfaces?

Comment: Look at the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Comment: @CSharpie, it just defines methods and properties common to all order objects. But I was thinking if I wanted to add unit tests later I could then use the interface to create mock order objects. I usually code against abstractions for this reason.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan, yes I was thinking about SOLID principles - see my comment above. I guess you always should depend on abstractions and not concrete types, hence the IOrder interface. And interface segregation principle - so I should not make all the interfaces inherit each other, because there might be a class at some point that may not need to implement all of the interface members? So the class should implement them separately?

Comment: Interface is contract. You need to think in terms of you domain. Which types of contracts you need and which contract must realize your entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`ISP (Interface Segregation Principle)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) rule, it should be that the `IOrder` interface implements the `IOrderState, IObservable` interfaces. So whichever class implements `IOrder`, it will also implement the other 2 interfaces.

So the 2nd case is more appropriate. i.e.

```
public interface IOrder : IOrderState, IObservable
```

Comment: But what if a different order type is added later and it doesn't need to be observed - it's then being forced to provide an implementation for the interface that is not needed (IObservable)

Comment: then your 1st proposal is more appropriate ;)

Comment: so experience matters in order to design a program efficiently, as an experienced architect can be able to foresee the scenarios that may occur subsequently during the overall application life cycle. He then tries to design in such a way so that the code can be easily extensible and manageable one

Comment: Your last comment makes alot of sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the Interfaces meaning. Though in your example it doesnt make much sense to seperate those interfaces since they look too close together.

However if you can think of a case where a class only needs IOrder and not those other two, you may want to split em up.

Lets take a look on access modifiers. If you inherit the interfaces, all could possibly be public visible for example.
If you only want your Orderstate and Observation internally, you have to split them up.

E.g. someone using your library should only know what is exposed by IOrder and not IOrderstate.

Comment: The separate interfaces are to implement the state pattern and observer pattern and to keep the code organisation clean. Maybe it doesn't matter, and maybe it's just down to how the system should work people will always have their own variation on an implementation like this?

Comment: I also create these separate interfaces to allow mock objects to be created for unit tests. If the methods were defined instead in one interface, I suppose they could be stubbed or still mocked.

Answer (score 1):

When designing types, you have to know about use-cases, or, at least, think about them.
When creating an interface, you should think about its possible implementations. Not every class should be complemented with interface.

When every class in your library looks like this:

```
interface IMyClass {}
class MyClass : IMyClass {}
```

then this is a cause to look at type design once again. There's large probability, that your class library goes to hell. I'm have to support some legacy code now, where almost every **internal** class has a coupled **internal** interface, and this class is a single inmplementation. Honestly, I'd like to forbid my former colleague to use interfaces any more.

If you could imagine any other `IOrder` impelmentation, then, make `IOrder` interface. Otherwise, throw it away (e.g., I can't imagine two or more different `IOrderState` implementations).

If every `IOrder` must be `IObservable`, then inherit `IOrder` from `IObservable`.
It completely depends on your use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

With your few info about your concrete use case the answer won't be very exact, but I'll try to give you some directives/hints.

Instead of a generic and common principle, I would say you need to think about your concrete scenario.

Perhaps you can ask yourself the following questions:

- Do all `IOrder` consumers require to *observe* the order? If this is the case, `IOrder` should *implement* `IObservable`.
- Do all `IOrder` consumers require to track orders state? If this is the case, `IOrder` should *implement* `IOrderState`.

Actually I would ask this kind of questions in order to determine what to do.

In the other hand, you can think about a more flexible architecture where *what `Order` should implement* can be defined by generic constraints:

```
public void Add<TOrder>(TOrder order) where TOrder : IOrder
{
}
```

But when you need to track order's state, you may do this:

```
public void SaveState<TOrder>(TOrder order) where TOrder : IOrder, IOrderState
{
}
```